# Why the telegram bot doesn`t recognize the url while the hashtag '#' is at the first of the message?

Tags: telegram-bot, hashtag

I have a telegram bot by `PHP` which removes messages which contain `url`, but when the the user send the hashtag `#` at the first of the message it doesn't remove the `url` !

```
$input=file_get_contents("php://input");
$update=json_decode($input,true);
$entity_type=$update['message']['entities'][0]['type'];
$chat_id=$update['message']['chat']['id'];
$message_id=$update['message']['message_id'];

if ($entity_type=='url' ){
    bot("deleteMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&message_id=".$msg_id);
}
```

forexample it removes `www.google.com` but doesn't remove 
`#info
www.google.com`

Why it doesn't recognize the url ? Is there any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

A message containing "`#info www.google.com`" has *two* entities.

You need to check if any of them is of type url.

Your code is checking only the first entity. (Which is of type `hashtag` and not `url`).

Comment: How can i check all the entities ? not only the first ? When the message is something like `Hello check the link : www.google.com` it also delete the message although the url is not at the begining

Comment: Instead of `$entity_type = $update['message']['entities'][0]['type']` you can do `$entity_array = $update['message']['entities']`  and iterate this array.